# Удаление первого и последнего символа по условию в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм вида:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'COL1': [',a1', ',a3', 'm100', 'w23'], 'COL2': [',a2', ',n1', ',k12', ','], 'COL3': ['a3', 'v4', '', 'y33'],
     'COL4': ['d1', ',v8', 'w54', 'e17']})
```

Как можно удалить в столбце на выбор первый символ, если он запятая. Так же и с последним символом - удалить если он занятая.
Спасибо.

Comment: Алгоритм: смотрим на первый символ. Если запятая - удалять. Точно так же с последним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Применяем `.apply` по нужной колонке, если первый/последний символ не запятая возвращаем значение без изменений, если запятая - возвращаем значение без первого/последнего символа.

```
df.COL1 = df.COL1.apply(lambda x: x if not x or x[0] != ',' else x[1:])
df.COL1 = df.COL1.apply(lambda x: x if not x or x[-1] != ',' else x[:-1])
```

По всему df применяем `.applymap`

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if not x or x[0] != ',' else x[1:])
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if not x or x[-1] != ',' else x[:-1])
```

Comment: А почему вы если первый символ - запятая, удаляете *и первый, и последний* символы?

Comment: @wchistow Вы стали свидетелем иллюстрации поговорки "Поспешишь - людей насмешишь". Спасибо, исправил. Также исправил проверку на пустую строку.

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь готовыми методами:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(','))
```

Если нужно провести эти операции только, например, в первой и последней колонках, то можно сделать через локатор:

```
df.iloc[:,[0,-1]] = df.iloc[:,[0,-1]].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(','), axis=1)
```

Comment: а про второй (третий и т.д), а так же предпоследний символы не сказано, что их нужно удалять :)

Comment: @Эникейщик я вот как-то не вижу этого в условии. но ответ дополнил )

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил воспользоваться регулярными выражениями и методом `.str.replace()` - на мой взгляд, это наиболее гибкий подход для данной задачи.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'COL1': [',,a1', ',a3', 'm100', 'w23'], 'COL2': [',a2', ',n1', ',k12', ','], 'COL3': ['a3', 'v4', '', 'y33'],
     'COL4': ['d1,', ',v8', 'w54,,,', 'e17']})

df.COL1 = df.COL1.str.replace('^,', '', regex=True)
df.COL4 = df.COL4.str.replace(',$', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

```
   COL1  COL2 COL3   COL4
0   ,a1   ,a2   a3     d1
1    a3   ,n1   v4    ,v8
2  m100  ,k12       w54,,
3   w23     ,  y33    e17
```

В данном примере в столбце `COL1` в первой и второй строке (по порядку) удалены по 1 запятой слева (в первой строке одна запятая осталась, т.к. их было 2). В столбце `COL4` в первой и третьей строке (по порядку) удалено по 1 запятой справа.
При необходимости удаления всех запятых слева или справа можно модифицировать регулярное выражение: `'^,+'` и `',+$'`. А c помощью выражения `',+$|^,+'` можно удалить любое количество запятых слева и справа. Можно также указать, какое количество запятых (или других символов) нужно удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так (пояснения в комментариях):

```py
def del_commas(s):
    if s:  # если строка не пустая
        if s[0] == ',':  # если первый символ - запятая
            s = s[1:]  # вырезаем его
        if s[-1] == ',':  # аналогично для последнего символа
            s = s[:-1]
    return s  # возвращаем получившуюся строку


for col in df.columns:  # в каждом столбце ...
    df[col] = df[col].apply(del_commas)  # ... убрать запятые
```

Comment: если и первый, и последний символы — запятая, то у вас удалится только первый

Comment: @Эникейщик, поправил.